# How to convert type object keys into an array of strings type in typescript

Tags: typescript

given the following input in typescript:

```
type InputObjectType = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: {}
}
```

how can I get the following type:

```
type ObjectKeysArrayType = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

so far I can only get as far as:

```
type AllPossibleKeys = (keyof InputObjectType)[]
```

which gives me `["a" | "b" | "c"]` which is close, but not what I'm looking for in this case.

I need an array that always contains all the key strings in the given type object. The only way I know to enforce this, for example when a user adds a new key to the object that the key is also added to the array is via something like this.

Comment: Is `InputObject` meant to be a type or an object? The name says one thing while the code says another.

Comment: I’ve updated the code, it is suppose to be a type.

Comment: ok, now can you explain how such a *String Array Literal* type would be useful? Because maybe the underlying problem is the one you should be asking. Types are erased in the output, so the only purpose they serve is for static type checking, or to construct other types for static type checking. In the later case `keyof InputObjectType` is all you need.  Otherwise this seems like an abstract exercise with no purpose, and probably doesn't belong on SO. **In other words, let's say what you ask isn't possible, which I think it isn't. Make the case to The Typescript folks why it should be.**

Comment: Also please change the title to be consistent with the question, or the other way around.

Comment: What you have should work (though I'm using v3.9). When I perform those same steps I get `("a"|"b"|"c")[]` which I believe is exactly what you want.

If instead you want an array that dynamically contains all those values, I don't believe that is possible as the Type doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution here, but hopefully this helps.

If what you want is a type that requires that the variable be an array of strings only containing values equal to the keys of your object, then what you have listed should work.

```
type InputObjectType = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: {}
}

type AllPossibleKeys = (keyof InputObjectType)[]
```

`AllPossibleKeys` will be a type equal to `("a"|"b"|"c")[]`. This looks to be what you've asked for, but there is a caveat with how I'm guessing you want to use this.

```
const fieldArray1: AllPossibleKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c']; //valid
const fieldArray2: AllPossibleKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; //will throw a Typescript error
const fieldArray3: AllPossibleKeys = ['a', 'b']; //this is also valid though as each member is a valid value
```

If you instead want an array of all the keys in a type, there's not a way to do this explicitly that I'm aware of. However, if you are able to use an interface instead of a type, then you can do the following:

```
import { keys } from 'lodash';

interface InputObject = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: {}
}

class InputObjectStub implements InputObject {
  a = null;
  b = null;
  c = null;
}

const fieldArray1 = keys(new InputObjectStub()); //returns ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Note though, that this won't enforce optional attributes. If you need to do that, change your class definition to `class InputObjectStub implements Required<InputObject> {...`

Edit: spelling

Comment: keyof was the key

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible because the type information is not available during runtime. You can try your code on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). When you do that, you'll find out that this code:

```js
type InputObjectType = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: {}
}
```

is transpiled to nothing. It simply doesn't exist after the code is transpiled to javascript. As it doesn't exist during runtime, no runtime action is possible, like iterate through its properties, or even print them out.

Comment: I'm not looking for this info in runtime, I want it for type checking.

Comment: Try to describe in your question what you want to do. People may suggest the right approach if they know your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I use two approaches:

```js
// Option 0: Define type using object
const someTypeExample = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'str',
  c: 'foo' as 'foo'|'bar'
};

type SomeType0 = typeof someTypeExample;


// Option 1: If object stores different types
type SomeType = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const typeVar: SomeType = {
    a: 10,
    b: 'string'
}

// used for typechecking
type SomeTypeKey = keyof SomeType;

// create an array to be used in runtime
// disadvantage is that properties need to be repeated
const keys: SomeTypeKey[] = ['a', 'b']; // type checked
// TODO what I'm missing is:
// const keys = keys<SomeTypeKey>(); that would return ['a', 'b'] during transpiling
// ie. native support of https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys 
// which is out of scope for TS: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13267
let isValidKey = keys.includes('c' as SomeTypeKey)


// Option 2: start from keys array definition, in case all values have the same type

const myKeys = ['foo', 'bar'] as const; // as const does the magic
type MyKey = typeof myKeys[number]; // = 'foo' | 'bar'

type MyMap = Record<MyKey, string>;
type MyMap2 = { [key in MyKey]: string };
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));

output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: can you use `Object.keys(object1)` in a type? I'm pretty sure not, I get `'Object' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

Comment: this does something different than asked.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.